# variables and methods and actionlisteners

Tags: java

I have this (partially pseudo)code

```
class a {
  void b()
  {
    int d = 0;
    JButton c = new JButton();
    c.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
        d = 1;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

However, it doesn't work, eclipse suggested adding final identifier to d, but that makes value impossible to change. Sorry if it's a stupid question, but it's hard to form a question for Google for something like this...
I also can't declare variable on lever higher than method b.

Comment: What do you actually want to do with `d`? What scope do you expect it to have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to move declaration of d outside of the method.

```
class a {
  int d = 0;

  method b() {
    JButton c = new JButton();
    c.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      d = 1;
    }
  }

}
```

..and format your code.

Comment: You cannot change anything in b() from the ActionListener. You have to rethink your code.

Comment: I thought before I couldn't move the variable outside the method, but I just had one of those "eureka" moments...

Answer (score 1):

It is because the code:

```
c.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
          {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
             {
                d = 1;
             }
          });//a little corrected here
```

Actually creates a new Nested Class and `overrides` the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method.
Since it is not the part of same class, the *secure* java does not allow *local* variables other than declared `final` to be accessed by that nested class method.